# Serialize and save data to a string

Tags: c#, serialization

I have this code here:

```
public xml.Sheet Sheet1 { get; set; }
```

I need to be able to serialize it and save the content in a string. Let's say `xml1`

I was able to do the deserialization but not the serialization.

The Sheet1 has Properties like:

```
Sheet1.Root
Sheet1.Controls
```

The XML file should be:

```
<Root>
<Control> </Control> 
<Control> </Control> 
<Control> </Control> 
</Root>

<Root>
<Control> </Control> 
<Control> </Control> 
<Control> </Control> 
</Root>
```

How do I start?

```
 XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(Sheet1.GetType());
```

Edit: my new code is this:

```
 public void GetContents(ref string xml1, ref string xml2)
        {

            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(Sheet1.GetType());
                ser.Serialize(writer, Sheet1);
                xml1 = writer.ToString();
            }


            using (var writer2 = new StringWriter())
            {
                XmlSerializer ser2 = new XmlSerializer(Sheet2.GetType());
                ser2.Serialize(writer2, Sheet2);
                xml2 = writer2.ToString();

            }

        }
```

Then I call this method:

```
compare.GetContents(ref xml1, ref xml2);
```

Now I get the new strings and how can I save them into XML files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Sheet` class needs to be marked as `[Serializable]`.  Also be aware only `public` properties and fields will be serialized.

```
string xml1;
using (var writer = new StringWriter()) 
{
  XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(Sheet1.GetType());
  ser.Serialize(writer, Sheet1);
  xml1 = writer.ToString();
}
```

And to save to a file:

```
using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter("filename.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
{
  fileWriter.Write(xml1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you :)
Question, how do i save it to a string?

Comment: Also, when i write this in my method, i get red underline in streamToWriteTo.

Comment: @Prov Edited to include writing to string.

Comment: sorry for my stupid comment but in the end i can say xml1 = writer.ToStrig() right?

Comment: Dear Zer0, i have a method that calls the string, i serialize two sheets, how can i modify it so i write the new strings in xml sheets?
I have this method:

dlg.GetXmlContents(ref xml1, ref xml2);  , sorry to bother

Comment: @Prov I'm not sure I understand your question.  Maybe edit your original question with some code?

Comment: I tried it and worked like a charm, could you please help me add an encoding here? UTF8